# website cannot be found unless I put IP address in host file

Tags: hosting, website

I have a client with a website, and it cannot be found unless I put it's name and the server ip address in the host file.  What would be causing this?  I've tried to access the site from multiple computers and I cannot access the site.

When I do a ping test on a site like just-ping.com I get several unknown hosts results and several packets lost.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Remember that in DNS www.domain.com is different from domain.com unless you are using wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that DNS is not configured correctly for the domain name. Have you tried doing an nslookup to see if the result matches the ip-address you expect?

Comment: Seconded—sounds like the domain isn't pointed to the server IP.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's clearly some DNS resolution issue. Check the DNS control panel on the corresponding domain registrar, and make sure the appropriate entry is in the DNS zone file - it could be just a CNAME or A record that's missing.

Are you trying to access a subdomain?